# Webfaction ImportError exception

Tags: django, web-hosting

Here is the stack trace:

```
ImportError at /admin/
No module named Cricket.getdate
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://cricket.debugger.pk/admin/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named Cricket.getdate
Exception Location: /home/yousuf/webapps/cricket/myproject/Cricket/models.py in       <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path:    
['/home/yousuf/webapps/cricket',
 '/home/yousuf/webapps/cricket/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/yousuf/lib/python2.7/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/yousuf/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Tue, 21 Feb 2012 15:49:04 -0600
```

However my `getdate.py` file is right there in the cricket folder, and it works fine on my local machine.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have a naming collision. Your WebFaction application instance folder name is 'cricket' and then you have an app module in 'myproject' that is also named 'Cricket'

Comment: This is not a stacktrace. Please, post the stacktrace.